# When is onStart triggered after installing an .MSI?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have generated a MSI from a Windows application project, where I have defined a service which derives from ServiceBase and contains:

```
public void override onStart(string[] args)
{
        //some code that changes something in my database
}
```

Does the executing of the onStart method require something else in addition to installing the .MSI? (maybe starting the service?)
Should my service appear in the list of services (services.msc) after installing the msi? Unsure how this all works. Thank you.

Comment: The `OnStart` method is called when the service is started.  NB: if you are using a case-sensitive language, you may need to correct the capitalization of your `OnStart` method.

Answer (score 0):

You usually need to have a ServiceInstaller class as well to create the service.  This will put the service into the list of services.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest taking a look at WiX (3.11) and IsWiX (latest)  and follow the pattern shown in this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bxbcPnjfzIc

(disclaimer, I run the IsWiX FOSS project on GitHub ).

The concept is you  use IsWiX to author the ServiceInstall and ServiceControl elements in your WiX project and this in turn teaches MSI how to install and start your service  (and stop/uninstall it when you remove the MSI).